# An easy question on complex

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Let $\{u_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a complex number sequence. If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{k}u_{k}=0$, for each $\lambda\in \mathbb{D}(0, 1/3)$(where the $\mathbb{D}(0, 1/3)~$denotes an open disc centered at $0$ and radius $1/3$). **Then can we conclude $u_{n}=0$, for $n=1, 2, 3...$ ?**

Comment: Indeed so, and thus the answer is yes, by the identity theorem

Comment: @DonAntonio: how to use identity theorem?

Comment: check here Theorem 1: http://planetmath.org/identitytheorem Basically, your function and the zero function are identical in $\;\Bbb D\;$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can.

Define a function $$f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty u_kz^k.$$ This function is defined, holomorphic, and constant on an open disk (a non-empty open connected set), so is constant everywhere. (Why?) In particular, then, all derivatives of the function will be identically $0,$ so since $$u_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$$ for all $k\ge 1,$ then we're done.

Comment: I have another question: If $\{u_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in an Banach algebra(or the set of all the bounded linear operators of a Banach space X), the conclusion is still true ?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure, off the top of my head. I've not worked with series outside of real and complex analysis, except in a strictly formal sense (without any evaluation).

Comment: Ok, thanks still. :P

Answer (score 1):

Let $n_0\in \Bbb N$ such that $u_{n_0}\neq 0$. Then $\sum_{k\neq n_0} λ^ku_k=-λu_{n_0}\neq 0$ for every $λ$.

Let $c_n$ be a decreasing sequence in $(0,1/3)$ such that $c_n\to 0$. Then $\sum_{k\neq n_0} (c_n)^ku_k=-(c_n)^{n_0}u_{n_0}\neq 0$. Then we have that $\lim_{n\to 0} \sum_{k\neq n_0} (c_n)^ku_k=0$. Contradiction.