# A question on a sequence in a Banach algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

If $\{u_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in an Banach algebra (and more specifically, in the set of all the bounded linear operators of a Banach space $X$). If $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda^{k}u_{k}=0,\quad \text{for every $\lambda\in \mathbb{D}(0, 1/3)$},$$
where the $\mathbb{D}(0, 1/3)~$ denotes an open disc centered at $0$ and radius $1/3$.

**Then can we conclude that $\boldsymbol{ u_{n}=0}$, for every $\boldsymbol{n}$?**

Comment: Yes, the proof is essentially the same as for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616551/an-easy-question-on-complex

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, it is still true that $u_{k}=\frac{f^{k}(0)}{k!}$, if $u_{k}$ is an element of a banach algebra?

Comment: That remains true. For an easy proof, apply a continuous linear functional $\mu$ to see that $\mu(u_k) = 0$ for all $k$. Since that holds for all $\mu$, Hahn-Banach says $u_k = 0$ for all $k$.

Comment: Ok, thanks Daniel~:P

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.

The fact that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda^k u_k=0$, for all $\lambda\in \mathbb D(0,1/3)$, implies that the sequence $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda^k u_k\in {\mathscr B}(X)$, $n\in\mathbb N,$ converges, for all $\lambda$, which implies that $\lambda^n u_n\to 0$, for every $|\lambda|<1/3$, thus $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\lambda|\|u_n\|^{1/n}\le 1 $, for every $|\lambda|<1/3$, and hence
$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|u_n\|^{1/n}\le 3,$ which in turn implies that the function
$$
f(\lambda)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda^k u_k, \quad \lambda\in\mathbb D(0,1/3),
$$
is in $C^\infty\big(\mathbb D(0,1/3);\mathscr B(X)\big)$. Since $f(\lambda)=0$, for every $\lambda\in \mathbb D(0,1/3)$, then $f^{(n)}(\lambda)=0$, for all $n$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb D(0,1/3)$. In particular $0=f^{(0)}(0)=u_n.\qquad$ QED